# I can't create key store in android studio when I generate release to publish it in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I want to generate release, but this error is appearing.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Didnt you just make a typo to `Andoid`?

Comment: Good spot, @Nicolas. Also @Ahmed, you may want to use something better as your key alias than `key0` (i.e. name of the app you sign it with etc)